# get name of activity within Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, ads, start-activity

I am using some various ad networks, they all require their own activity names to be added to the manifest.

I want to know when users click them, so I put in an override for `startActivity(Intent intent)` but I need to inspect the intent object to conditionally set some values.

for instance, with tap for tap's network, it will launch an activity from the class `com.ads.TapForTap`.. upon a click this will call startActivity(Intent intent) how do I get the name of the class from the intent?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try below line to get current activity name,

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Comment: I need to get it from an intent object. not from the current class. this might work though

Comment: this did get the name of the activity, by its name but not the package name. Which is fine, I can use this

Answer (score 27):

You can use the given intent argument's component class name. Remember the class name might be empty!

[`intent.getComponent().getClassName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#getClassName())

Comment: Please annotate your answer to make it helpful.  We don't need copy/paste solutions.  We need to help questioners and readers understand the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The following line should return the fully qualified name of the Activity you want to start if you have:

- The Intent that starts an Activity
- A Context instance (so you can call `getPackageManager()`).

---

```
String className = myIntent.resolveActivity (myContext.getPackageManager()).getClassName();
```

For more info, see the `Intent` documentation for [`resolveActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29).

Comment: @CQM Did you try it? Based on my tests it gives you the full name (com.package.ActivityName), but maybe I misread what you wanted.

Comment: at the time I needed really any way to differentiate between packages, to solve my underlying problem what I did was `if(!context.getClass().getSimpleName().contentEquals(""))` as this condition would only get triggered when one of the various ad networks were clicked, and since I might be adding more I didn't need to more specifics